# How to minimize bundle size by improving import way of lodash?

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, lodash

how do you import lodash into your projects?

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

As far as I understand, if you are importing as above, this includes the entire lodash library in the bundle. To shrink the bundle size,

```
import get from 'lodash/get'
```

When you import it as , it only includes the get function in the bundle. But if too many lodash functions are used, there are too many import lines. I have installed a package called **babel-plugin-transform-imports** for this. with this package

```
import { get } from 'lodash'
```

and only includes functions that are required (in this example, get) at build time. But when I examine the bundle with source-map-analyzer, the bundle gets bigger, interestingly enough.

It decreases the build size of the Component that I applied by **2.5KB**, but the total app itself increases by **1KB**.

Has anyone dealt with this before? What do you do for this?

Comment: You can check [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) from Webpack which may be related to your question